# How do I add users to a Blazor Server app via a custom form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, blazor, blazor-server-side

How do I add users to a Blazor Server app?

I have disabled the `Register as a new user` button on the login page and the top. I don't want anyone to just come and create a user.
I have created a `AddUsersPage` which I want to use for adding users to the app. The person that creates the user should be able to add the user and define a role (`Administrator` or `User`)
I have created a custom Database. The default tables have been created for authentication and the roles have been defined.
I'm very new to Blazor programming... any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create users using `UserManager` which is used for CRUD operations on identity users. Below is some code to add users and assign them roles.

Firstly inject the `UserManager` in your class where you are creating users.

```
var user = new IdentityUser();
user.Email = "test@email.com";
...
var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "PASSWORD");

if (result.Succeeded)
{
   await userMgr.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User");
}
```

See more details here for [UserManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-3.1)